# prefixed PYTHONPATHs not in sys.path for embedded Python

Tags: python, windows-10, python-3.5

In the following structure:

```
- foobar
  - __init__.py
  - pyfoo
    - __init__.py
    - foo.pyd
    - src
      - __init__.py
      - test
        - __init__.py
        - bar.py
```

I try to load `foo.pyd` from `bar.py`.
Therefor I inserted an entry into `PYTHONPATH` with `\\?\C:\<path_to_foobar>\foobar\pyfoo`.

In `bar.py` I then try to

```
import foo
```

, which never finds `foo`.

Now when I look at `sys.path`, entries from `PYTHONPATH` are missing.
Also, when I look under which paths `foo.pyd` is searched, only paths of `sys.path` are taken into account.

So how come `sys.path` does not contain all paths of `PYTHONPATH`?

---

**EDIT:**

To test the paths I inserted logs right before import:

```
print("SP %s" % sys.path)
print("PP %s" % os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])
```

Which gives me something like:

```
SP ['\\\\?\\B:\\foobar\\pyfoo\\src\\test', 'C:\\python3\\win_x86_64\\python35.zip', 'C:\\python3\\win_x86_64\\DLLs', 'C:\\python3\\win_x86_64\\lib', 'C:\\python3\\win_x86_64']
PP \\?\B:\;\\?\B:\foobar\pyfoo;\\?\B:\foobar;\\?\B:\foobar\pyfoo
```

Comment: how did you insert your PYTHONPATH entry? are you sure that the variable is defined where you're running your script? you may echo PYTHONPATH before starting your script. Clearly a [mcve] is missing here.

Comment: See Edit, I am not only echoing before but in the Script.

Comment: I understand you replaced your server name by `?`. If not there's a first problem: this cannot be a valid path. And the other error is the drive `:` which should be `$` in the case of UNC paths with drives. Your UNC paths doesn't seem valid.

Comment: `\\?\` is a long-path prefix on Windows. Read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok, so it's valid windows-wise. do you _really_ need that? can you try without?

Comment: Yes I _really_ need that, because our paths exceed MAX_PATH. But you might be onto something. Perhaps sys.path building cannot handle these!?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Using \\?\ in PYTHONPATH works just fine.

Comment: yes, that what I was implying.

Comment: @JoshLee Are you sure? I mean really really sure ;)

Comment: as a workaround, you could try: `sys.path.extend(os.getenv("PYTHONPATH").split(os.pathsep))` to add the contents of PYTHONPATH to `sys.path` explicitly _before_ trying to import your module.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre With that it works.

Comment: it may be related to long path prefix _and_ `.pyd` module types altogether BTW.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't think so because when looking into the import trace, it does not yet know whether it is a normal .py or .pyd file and just searches directories. The problem really seems to come down to why PYTHONPATH entries are not in sys.path

Comment: works for me, check my edit. What's your python version.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce your problem, with my Windows 7-x64 + python 3.4.4-x64 version it works, contents of `PYTHONPATH` are present in `sys.path`:

```
set PYTHONPATH=\\?\L:\SO
python

>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '\\\\?\\L:\\SO', ... , 'D:\\Python34-x64\\lib\\site-packages']
```

That said, as a workaround, you could force the contents of `PYTHONPATH` into `sys.path` like this:

```
import os,sys
sys.path.extend(os.getenv("PYTHONPATH").split(os.pathsep))

# now you can import foo
import foo
```

Comment: Can you try to call a script with prefixed path please?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64-bit. What version of python are _you_ using?

Comment: Python3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: Python 3.6 is still new. You may be on to something here. Could you try with an older version by your end? (note: I edited the tags of your question to reflect python 3.6)

Comment: 3.4.4 works for me on two Windows 10 installations. So seems like it broke somewhere between 3.4.4 and 3.6.0

Comment: let me download anaconda 3.6 and I'll check by my end.

Comment: So I now have a Python 3.5.2-embeddable Python on which this fails. All other variants (3.4.4-installer, 3.5.2-installer, 3.6.0-installer) worked. Will test a 3.6.0-embeddable.

Comment: Same fail in 3.6.0-embeddable. Seems like something is different there

Answer (score 0):

Trying (with 3.5.2-embeddable):

```
set PYTHONPATH=\\?\C:\Windows

C:\python3.5.2\win_x86_64\python.exe \\?\C:\temp\test.py
```

with `test.py`:

```
import os
import sys

print("SP %s" % sys.path)
print("PP %s" % os.environ["PYTHONPATH"])
```

Leads to `\\?\C:\Windows` being missing from `sys.path`.

Making the same test with `set PYTHONPATH=C:\Windows` works like a charm in 3.5.2-embeddable.

The same test with 3.6.0-embeddable does not add to `sys.path` in any case.

And 3.6.0-embeddable seems like the intended behavior https://bugs.python.org/issue28245